# Apache24 Windows Proxy

Tags: windows, apache, proxy

I'm trying to use Apache24 as a proxy/reverse proxy to forward requests from port 80 to port 8088.  I can access my website on port 8088 when I type the port in the browser and I get the "It works" page from apache24 on port 80. I have these modules loaded httpd.conf

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

And I'm using the following proxy commands

```
ProxyPass /software-suite/ http://localhost:8088/software-suite/
ProxyPassReverse /software-suite/ http://localhost:8088/software-suite/
```

But I get "This page can't be displayed" in IE when I try http://localhost/software-suite

Comment: HI, are you also changing the host header?  For http requests to non-standard ports, the host header will contain the port number as well, but that won't be what you're receiving from a request to port 80 since that's the standard port.  I see you're also trying nginx for this, if you'd like to try another proxy - our product [WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) we can help you set it up. it's free for 10 concurrently-connected users, so may not fit your needs in that regards.  Disclaimer I work for Qbik who make WinGate.

Comment: How do you change the host header?